# Please help configuring NVIDIA-SMI Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL 2

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, microsoft

Following [this announcement](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/) and somewhat trying to follow [this confusing thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failure-to-install-cuda-on-wsl-2-ubuntu/128592), I

- installed Windows Version 10.0.20150 Build 20150
- installed NVidia Driver version 455.51
- installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the Windows Store

I started Ubuntu and tried to run NVIDIA-SMI.  It told me it wasn't there but that I could install it with one of these options:

```
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-340        # version 340.108-0ubuntu2, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390  # version 390.132-0ubuntu2
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-435  # version 435.21-0ubuntu7
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440  # version 440.82+really.440.64-0ubuntu6
```

Note that there is no `nvidia-utils-450` option corresponding to my 455.51, which the NVidia thread above said somewhere is required to make things go.  I then ran

```
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-440
nvidia-smi
```

and it said "No devices found".

Then I found [this guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/).  I uninstalled Ubunto 20.04, and then followed the guide.  The guide asked me to

- install a vanilla Ubuntu (no release number), which I did instead of 20.04.  (This turns out to give me 20.04).
- install Windows Terminal (I chose the Preview version)
- check to receive updates for related Windows programs
- update the kernel to 4.9.121
- install NVIDIA CUDA drivers on Windows 10 (I already did 455, have to check the CUDA release)
- install Docker
- install NVidia Container Toolkit
- test

The "install docker" part of that guide seems to be buggy.  I couldn't get docker service to start.  So I uninstalled my Ubuntu and repeated the steps up to that point, without touching Docker.  Then (my version), the steps from the Docker point are (for docker part I am following [these instructions to get Docker](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04)):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce
sudo systemctl status docker
```

The last step fails.  I get this message:

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

That led me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operatehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate) and the 4th and almost lowest-scored answer seems to work, except it needs to be run in background mode:

```
sudo dockerd &
sudo usermod -aG docker your-user
```

Then I go back to [the guide post-Docker install step](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/) and resume with

```
docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark
```

and this fails with

```
ERRO[2020-06-23T07:28:28.582848400-04:00] 5cd9b9d7011ba20f72971dd27900b23b2c0f6be656b0bd53b9e178944fe4eba6 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container
ERRO[2020-06-23T07:28:28.582946600-04:00] Handler for POST /v1.40/containers/5cd9b9d7011ba20f72971dd27900b23b2c0f6be656b0bd53b9e178944fe4eba6/start returned error: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
ERRO[0018] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Finally I went back to the [NVidia announcement](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/) and did these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/experimental/$distribution/libnvidia-container-experimental.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libnvidia-container-experimental.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo dockerd &
docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark
```

**SUCCESS**: and I got a happy result:

```
> Windowed mode
> Simulation data stored in video memory
> Single precision floating point simulation
> 1 Devices used for simulation
GPU Device 0: "Quadro M500M" with compute capability 5.0

> Compute 5.0 CUDA device: [Quadro M500M]
3072 bodies, total time for 10 iterations: 3.817 ms
= 24.724 billion interactions per second
= 494.487 single-precision GFLOP/s at 20 flops per interaction
```

**HOWEVER**, per answer below, there is no NVIDIA-SMI, per [known NVIDIA limitations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations).

**FURTHER NOTE**: The docker container test above works on Ubuntu shell. It does **not** work on Windows Powershell Preview with the Ubuntu tab.

Comment: Note that you can run the Windows version of nvidia-smi from inside wsl.

Comment: "The docker container test above works on Ubuntu shell. It does not work on Windows Powershell Preview with the Ubuntu tab." So on top of a real Windows OS, you need to run Ubuntu WSL2, and then Docker from within that Ubuntu WSL2, to get to use Nvidia's CUDA containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nbody works then you have everything well configured. The problem is NVIDIA drivers limitations.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations

`NVIDIA Management Library (NVML) APIs are not supported.`

nvidia-smi is based on top of the NVIDIA Management Library (NVML).

Answer (score 3):

An update as of Apr 25, 2022
`nvidia-smi` is now supported on WSL2

After successful installation of CUDA following official nvidia doc:

```bash
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin
sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.4.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local_11.4.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-11-4-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

You should have `nvidia-smi` available at `/usr/lib/wsl/lib/nvidia-smi` so you can just add `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` to `PATH` to easily run `nvidia-smi`.

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/wsl/lib/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

An update to @onoma's answer. From https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations :

```
6. nvidia-smi is not yet packaged for CUDA on WSL 2.
```

Hopefully this will be solved in future by nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Nvidia-smi running an WSL2 as well.
My OS build was 19043.2130, version 21H1.
The solution was to update my Windows 10. I updated to the November 2021 Windows 10 version, which seemingly successfully passed down the NVidia connection to WSL.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
After the update, the version became OS Build 19044.2130, version 21H2

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions, `nvidia-smi` is supported on WSL2 by default, just install the required Windows CUDA driver, and the WSL2 packages come along with it.
On a side note, if `nvidia-smi` does not directly work on WSL2 terminal, try `nvidia-smi.exe`.
If it doesn't work, check if the required directory (something like `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` or `/lib/wsl/lib`) is added to PATH, refer https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-through-wsl2/180310 for more details on it.